How to resolve "Entry point Not Found" in release mode
I am developing one DLL in VC++ and its working while testing with my Test.exe app in debug mode. But while running Test.exe in release mode I am getting "Entry point Not Found" error
While checking properties of both release and debug mode both are same other than path, one to Debug and other to Release path


You might have wrapped something in an #ifdef so it only exists in debug builds.  You might have made a code change to the DLL and then only rebuilt the debug version so release is missing the changes.

My DLl is wevy small component with 3 source files, I didnt use any #ifdef. I am using fmt.dll file and the screenshot telling somethign related to FMT I feel
